# how to turn off "Warning as Error" option in the MonoDevelop 4.0.3?

Tags: monodevelop

i got a large project from GitHub I'm trying to compile and these errors just drive me nuts:

> Error CS0219: Warning as Error: The variable `memberInfo' is assigned
>   but its value is never used (CS0219)

Thank you.

Comment: +1 for a hint how to disable it at the command line.

Answer (score 2):

It's in the project options.
Open the project options and go to :

build->compiler

There is a checkbox:

warnings as errors

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project in the Solution Explorer:
options --> build --> compiler --> set Warning Level to 2.